# Sorting strings in format HH:mm in array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an Array like this one:

```
$x = array(
    array(
        'inicio' => '09:00',
        'fim' => '09:30'
    ),
    array(
        'inicio' => '09:30',
        'fim' => '10:00'
    ),
    array(
        'inicio' => '08:30',
        'fim' => '09:00'
    ),
    array(
        'inicio' => '11:30',
        'fim' => '12:00'
    )
);
```

I have to ordenate this by `inicio` field. I am trying to use `usort` liket this but I only get 1 as result:

```
$y = usort($x, function($a, $b) {
    return (explode(':', $b['inicio'])[0]*60 + explode(':', $b['inicio'])[1]) - (explode(':', $a['inicio'])[0]*60 + explode(':', $a['inicio'])[1]);
});

print_r($y);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st, [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) does not return array, it is sorted in place. Doc says:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

2nd, you can just compare inicio fields

```
usort($x, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['inicio'], $b['inicio']); });
print_r($x);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. My shame I didn't see this on documentation.